# Mocking multiple MediatR sends in one comon handler

Tags: mocking, handler, cqrs, mediatr

I have an AssetMovement MediatR handler, where I insert a new assetmovement documnet. This action also affects two other tables; I have to update the asset avalability and insert the new location of asset into AssetLocation table.

AssetAvailableFetatures has an Update handler and AssetLocationFeatures has an Insert handler. These two handler are send in AssetMovementFeatures.Insert handler, which has an AssetMovementRepository, too.

```
private readonly IMediator _mediator;
private readonly IGenericRepository<AssetMovement> _assetMovementeRepository;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public Handler(
  IGenericRepository<Domain.Entities.AssetMovement> 
  assetMovementeRepository,
  IMediator mediator, IMapper mapper)
{
    _assetMovementeRepository = assetMovementeRepository;
    _mediator = mediator;
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var assetMovement = _mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.AssetMovement>(request.AssetMovementOutTakeDto);

  var adminId = await _mediator.Send(new User.GetUserIdByName.Query { UserName = request.AdminName });
  assetMovement.AdministratorId = adminId;

  foreach (var item in assetMovement.AssetMovementItems)
  {
    await _mediator.Send(new AssetAvailableFeatures.Update.Command { 
          AssetId = item.Asset.Id, 
          QualityId = item.Asset.QualityId, 
          Quantity = -item.Quantity });

    await _mediator.Send(new AssetLocationFeatures.Update.Command { 
        AssetId = item.Asset.Id, 
        UserId = (int)assetMovement.PartnerUserId, 
        PartnerId = assetMovement.PartnerId, 
        Quantity = item.Quantity });
  }

  await _assetMovementeRepository.AddAsync(assetMovement);
  await _assetMovementeRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
  return Unit.Value;
}
```

My first question is, am I on the right track? Is this separation of different functionalities good? My second how I can mock the three mediator sends:

1. _mediator.Send(new User.GetUserIdByName.Query,
2. _mediator.Send(new AssetAvailableFeatures.Update.Command,
3. _mediator.Send(new AssetLocationFeatures.Update.Command

because only the mediator itself is in the handler constructor and then the different command sends are in the body of the handler.